# I sent money from my BTC (Blockchain) to BCC (coinbase) by accident. Any help to recover the funds? Both accounts are owned by me

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key, trading, bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

I sent money from my BTC (Blockchain) to BCC (coinbase) by accident. Any help to recover the funds?

I need help as I know transactions cannot be refunded but I have read a few forums where people have recovered it.